# Encountering Infinite loop in case of string handling

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

class Time
{
    int hours=0,scan_hours=0;
    int minutes=0,scan_minutes=0;

public:

void input_time_in_format_1(void)
{
    cout<<"\n\t Enter the time in the format hh:mm A.M./P.M.:  ";
    if(scanf("%d",&hours)==1)
    {
        if(scanf(":%d A.M.",&minutes)==1)
        {   
            hours=(hours+12)%24;
                if(hours>13||minutes>60||hours<0||minutes<0)
                {   
                    cout<<"\n\t Wrong entry";
                    hours=minutes=0;
                }
                else    
                    cout<<"\n\t Your time has been accepted";
        }
        else if(scanf(":%d P.M.",&minutes)==1)
        {
            if(hours>13||minutes>60||hours<0||minutes<0)
                {   
                    cout<<"\n\t Wrong entry";
                    hours=minutes=0;
                }

            else
                cout<<"\n\t Your time has been accepted";   
        }   
        else
        {   
            cout<<"\n\t Wrong entry";
            hours=0;
            minutes=0;
        }

    }
    else
    {   
        cout<<"\n\t Wrong entry";
        hours=0;
    }


}
void input_time_in_format_2(void)
{
    cout<<"\n\t Enter the time in the format hh:mm hours:  ";
    if(scanf("%d",&hours)==1 && hours<24)
    {
        if(scanf(":%d hours",&minutes)==1 && minutes<60)
            cout<<"\n\t Your time has been accepted";

        else
        {   
            cout<<"\n\t Wrong entry";
            hours=minutes=0;
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        cout<<"\n\t Wrong entry";
        hours=0;
    }
}


void show_time_in_format_1(void)
{
    cout<<"\n\t Showing time in 24 hours format: "<<hours<<":"<<minutes<<" hours";
}

void show_time_in_format_2(void)
{
    if(hours>12)
        cout<<"\n\t Showing time in 12 hours format: "<<(hours%12)<<":"<<minutes<<" P.M.\n\n";
    else
        cout<<"\n\t Showing time in 12 hours format: "<<hours<<":"<<minutes<<" A.M.\n\n";
}
void add_time(void)
{
    cout<<"\n\t Please enter the hours and minutes respectively";
    cin>>scan_hours;
    cin>>scan_minutes;
    if(minutes+=scan_minutes>=60)
    {
        hours+=(scan_hours+1);
        hours%=24;
    }
    else
    {
        hours+=(scan_hours);
        hours%=24;
    }
}


};

int main()
{
    Time t1;
    int choice;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\n\t\t\t --Welcome--"<<"\n\n\t Please enter your choice \n\t1.Input time in 12 hours format\n\t2.Input time in 24 hours format\n\t3.Show time in 12 hours format\n\t4.Show time in 24 hours format\n\t5.Add user input time\n\t6.Exit....-->";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:cin.ignore();
                t1.input_time_in_format_1();
                break;

            case 2:
                t1.input_time_in_format_2();
                break;

            case 3:
                t1.show_time_in_format_2();
                break;

            case 4:
                t1.show_time_in_format_1();
                break;

            case 5:
                t1.add_time();
                break;

            case 6:
                cout<<"\n\t Thank You";
                exit(0);

            default:
                cout<<"\n\n\t Wrong entry";
                break;

        }

}while(1);

return 0;
}
```

This is my program to accept a date from the user and to print it in different format. If I choose the **case 1** whenever I want to give any input,weather it be correct or wrong, it leads me to an infinite loop. I couldn't find out what's going on. i think I have handled all the exceptions.Feel free to dump it, if you wish.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through each of you loops with a debugger??

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Then no better time like the present to learn how to use a debugger. It's not that hard to get started and is an essential skill for any serious developer. If on Linux then [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) is one of the common debuggers to use.

Comment: 1) the statement: `using namespace std:` is usually the wrong thing to do.  2) this is a C++ program, so please remove the `c` tag

Comment: Can you suggest from where I could learn?@kaylum

Comment: in general, follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: The link to the gdb documentation is provided in the previous comment. Alternatively, do a search for gdb tutorials.

Comment: As I am dealing with scanf() , I mustn't remove the c tag, do I ?

Comment: Calling `scanf` doesn't make it a C program. Your code is clearly C++ and not C (they are different languages) so please do remove the C tag.

Comment: `scanf` exists in C and C++. `cin` does not exist in C.  This is therefore  C++ and not C.

Comment: while a single blank line is very good for separating code blocks, (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) and two blank lines is very good for separating methods (all for readability)  that readability drops way off, very quickly when inserting multiple blank lines in a method, with no logical reason for their existence.

Comment: if the user input contains `AM`, then why modify the clock for `PM`?

Comment: I didn't modify it. I have given a check condition for both **AM** and **PM**

Comment: regarding this line: `cout<<"\n\t Enter the time in the format hh:mm A.M./P.M.:  ";`   this can/will be a bit confusing to the user.  suggest: `cout<<"\n\t Enter the time in the format hh:mm [A.M.|P.M.]:  ";

Comment: this code block: `if(scanf(":%d A.M.",&minutes)==1)
        {   
            hours=(hours+12)%24;` modifies the time as if the user had entered `P.M.`

Comment: regarding this line: `case 1:cin.ignore();`  why are the other case(s) and functions that input a line from the user not calling the function: `cin.ignore()`  (I;m assuming this call is to consume any white space, like the newline

Comment: I would suggest (not mandatory for this simple project) that a header file be created for this class, the class body be in a separate file, and the main source file #include the class header file.

Comment: Suggest a constructor method for the class that sets the 4 variables to 0 rather than initializing them as is currently being done

Comment: This is a weird usage of `scanf`:  `scanf(":%d P.M.",&minutes)`  What's the "P.M". about?  The `scanf` function's job is to get input, not display messages or prompts.

Comment: in method: `input_time_in_format_1()` once the user's input has been consumed via the first call to `scanf()` that input is no longer available for the second call to `scanf()`  This method needs some significant re-design

Comment: regarding this line: `if(scanf("%d",&hours)==1 && hours<24)`  if the user entered `-36`, this line would accept that entry.  Suggest: `if(scanf("%u",&hours)==1 && hours<24)`  Note the use of the 'unsigned' format specifier.  This same consideration needs to be applied to all the calls to `scanf()`

Comment: it is (almost) always better to `cin` the whole line, then parse the fields from the line.  (perhaps by using `sscanf()`, although there are plenty of other ways)  then there is no problem of alternate line formats as expressed/expected in the method: `input_time_in_format_1`.

Answer (score 0):

the most likely cause of the problem is the line:

```
cin >> choice;
```

This is failing because the istream contains a newline and this will cause the `cin` to fail.

Suggest calling:

```
cin.ignore();
```

before outputting the prompt/menu then the istream will be empty and the response to the menu, as input by the user, will be placed into the variable `choice;